# Redirect to created content from a dynamic form

Tags: orchardcms

The Dynamic Forms module has two handy features: Creating content using bindings from the form, and redirecting the page after the form's submission.

I would like to be able to redirect to the new content item after the form has been submitted. Is this possible through the current set of tokens or other available feature?

I've tested out using various combinations of workflows and the `{Request.Content.*}` token so far.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you the content you are using is a custom content type "Animal" and you have a form field named "AnimalName" that is set to TitlePart in Bindings. You have the form (named "Create an Animal") set to create an Animal content item and publish it.

For this example, make sure that the Autoroute for Animal is set to `{Content.Slug}` in the content definition.

Create a workflow that starts with "Dynamic Form Submitted" for "Create an Animal". Set a Redirect as the next step with the URL `/{FormSubmission.Field:AnimalName.Slug}`.

Comment: Unfortunate that it requires the autoroute to use the title; I'm already using a differently patterned route for this type. I'll write something custom for it then.

Comment: Not able to find a way to even extract the ID of the new content item from a custom controller function or workflow activity, so I think I'll have to do something daft like just query the database for the newest instance of that content type.